# connect sliders using a line in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I need to connect sliders using a line in shiny as can be seen from the image,i.e., i need to physically draw lines between the sliders[image]

How could this be done.
Thanks

Comment: @dan1111:Physically draw a line such as in the picture

Comment: It definitively requires VERY good skills in Javascript, HTML and Shiny to get it to work.

Comment: ...and CSS and SVG  I reckon. Have an SVG overlay and events hooked to the sliders so that on change you draw an arrow on the SVG. Possible, but not something I'd want to do.